# VSCode Python debugger runs but nothing happens

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, vscode-debugger

I have recently bought a new laptop and set up VSCode and Python so I can continue coding. Everything looks fine, took a bit of messing around to get virtual environments working, but apart from that no problem EXCEPT my code does not run.

To be specific, when I open my code and click "Run | Start Debugging (F5)", for an instant the little toolbar of debug buttons (run, step-over, etc) pops up and disappears, but the code in the window does not run, there is no output to the terminal, nothing happens!

A screenshot of my entire VSCode screen is below.
[image: VSCode Window]

My launch.json file is below.

```
    {
    // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
    // Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
    // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [

        {
            "type": "chrome",
            "request": "launch",
            "name": "Launch Chrome against localhost",
            "file": "${workspaceFolder}/web/_test/book.html"
        },
    
        {
            "name": "Python: Current File",
            "type": "debugpy",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "${file}",
            "console": "integratedTerminal"
        },

        {
            "name": "Python: Flask (development mode)",
            "type": "debugpy",
            "request": "launch",
            "module": "flask",
            "env": {
                "FLASK_APP": "flask_run.py",
                "FLASK_ENV": "development"
            },
            "args": [
                "run"
            ],
            "jinja": true
        }
    ]
}
```

I have all the python extensions installed.

[image]

Comment: what is in the breakpoint() function? Also, do you have the correct version of Python installed on your PC? You should be able to check inside VSCode. At the bottom right corner, you will see the 3.9.0(.venv...) you should be able to click on that and view all the versions of python available.

Comment: is the path set for the python in Environment Variables?

Answer (score 1):

Click on python version in the lower right corner, then select switch to `python 3.12.1` in the list.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Hi @JialeDu , thanks, when I do that my code runs! BUT now my .venv environment and the version of python in it does not seem to be getting used. This was the problem I had before the no-run problem. How do I make VSCode run my code using the .venv environment?

Comment: How did you create your virtual environment python version 3.9? Do you have python 3.9 installed on your machine? If installed, where is the path?

Comment: Hi @JialeDu, that is where it gets interesting. My python folder is on OneDrive. Everything worked on my old laptop including the venv. I got a new laptop and installed python and vscode. It is the new laptop that is having the problems. Although the venv is there, when vscode uses it I get the problem above. The whole point of the venv is that it shouldn't matter what version is in there. How do I get vscode to recognise the venv folder on OneDrive and use the interpreter in it.

Comment: Can you please answer the question instead of talking about yourself. Show your python version and installation path.

Answer (score 1):

For me in some virtual environments with some scripts, adding `"justMyCode": false` to the config in my `launch.json` did actually help with this problem. Here is the documentation: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/debugging#_justmycode

Comment: Hi @balintd. I tried that and you are right in that the code now runs, but it is using the global interpreter not the one in the venv. Directly selecting the global interpreter also works. So literally you have solved my problem, but the root problem I was trying to solve was how to get my venv working.